# Find the Marginal Distribution of a density function and E[X] and E[Y]

Tags: probability-theory

I have a question on a practice exam paper on Marginal densities. I have answered it and think my answer is correct but would like someone to check for me as i do not have the full solutions.

Let X and Y have joint density $f(x,y)=1/x$ on $0<y<x<1$ and zero otherwise.

I need to find the Marginal Densities of $X$ and $Y$ and $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$

To find the Marginal Densities of $X$ and$Y$ I have checked that

$$\int\int_R f(x,y) \, dx \, dy = 1=
\int_{0}^1\int_{y}^1 1/x \, dx \, dy$$

Then i have that the marginal density of X is $0$ for $x<0$, $x=0$ and for $x>0$ we have
$$f_X(x)=\int_{0}^x 1/x \, dy = [y/x]=x/x = 1$$

and i have that the marginal density of $Y$ is $0$ for $y<0$, $y=0$ and for $y>0$ we have
$$f_Y(y)=\int_{y}^0 1/x \, dx = [\ln x]= -\ln x$$

Now to find $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$ I have

$$E[X] =\int_{0}^1 xf_X(x) \, dx=\int_{0}^1 (x)(1) \, dx =\int_{0}^1 x \, dx = [x]=1$$

$$E[Y] =\int_{0}^1 yf_Y(y) \, dy=\int_{0}^1 (y)(-\ln y) \, dy = [1/4y^2(1-2\ln y)]=1/4$$

Could someone please tell me if I have done this correctly, and if not, please point out where I have gone wrong and why?

Many thanks

Comment: your marginal density for $X$ is wrong - I got the feeling you don't want to know exactly where. Your mean of X is wrong as well (more so than just using the wrong density). Oh, and, this is a detail, look at variable you integrate over finding your marginals.

Comment: Oh no really? Damn.. No i would like to know where please! I really thought i had it right but thought the marginal density of X probably shouldnt be 1/x...

Comment: Don't tell anyone, but the first time I learned this I messed it up every time. To find the marginal of X integrate out _y_ and between 0 and x. Your density will be 0 outside $[0,1]$ so when finding the mean this is the area to integrate over (Y is out of the picture when you've got the marginals.)

Comment: Ah okay thanks I will try that and edit the question.. Haha i have just learned this too, its the very end of my into to probability course! Are my integral limits correct up until this? Many thanks! Will change the answer now and see if it is correct.

Comment: As it stands now the two integrals giving you the marginals are wrong (you get the right result for Y though, so maybe its a typo) and the mean of X.

Comment: The calculations of the marginals do not make sense. For expectations, you can use the marginals or calculate directly from the joint density.

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer. If someone could confirm if this is correct or where i have gone wrong i would be very grateful! Many thanks

Comment: Was the typo for density of Y, dy instead of dx? If so i have changed to dx now, as it was meant to be. I have also changed dx to dy for the density of X, as also was meant to be.

Comment: @Bernard.Mathews your density $f_Y(y)=-ln(x)$ this really should make you wonder. You can write $[\ln(x)]_y^0=-\ln(y)$. Dids answer is probably a bit technical for you, but he is right in the sense that you _really_ have to think of a density as a function and where it is positive e.g. $1$ and the interval $0<x<1$ for $X$. This part you are still a bit unclear on (see text up to each derivation of marginals).

Answer (score 1):

A spectacular example of the mess and head-scratching that can occur when one fails to write down densities rigorously. Recall that the density of a couple $(X,Y)$ of random variables is always a function $f$ **defined on the whole real plane**. Here, using the proper (and crucial) indicator function,
$$
f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R_+,\qquad (x,y)\mapsto x^{-1}\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt x\lt 1}.
$$
My stance is that, if one starts from this writing (a benign modification if ever there was such), one cannot fail...

Density of $X$? This is the function $f_X$ **defined on the whole real line** by
$$
f_X(x)=\int_\mathbb Rf(x,y)\mathrm dy=\int_\mathbb Rx^{-1}\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt x\lt 1}\mathrm dy.
$$
To factor as many terms that does not depend on $y$ as one can, use the identity $\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt x\lt 1}=\mathbf 1_{0\lt x\lt1}\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt x}$ (do you agree that it holds?). Thus,
$$
f_X(x)=x^{-1}\mathbf 1_{0\lt x\lt1}\int_\mathbb R\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt x}\mathrm dy=x^{-1}\mathbf 1_{0\lt x\lt1}\int_0^x\mathrm dy=\mathbf 1_{0\lt x\lt1}.
$$
And it always works... Density of $Y$? This is the function $f_Y$ **defined on the whole real line** by
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_\mathbb Rf(x,y)\mathrm dx=\int_\mathbb Rx^{-1}\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt x\lt 1}\mathrm dx.
$$
This time, rewrite the indicator function as $\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt x\lt 1}=\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt1}\mathbf 1_{y\lt x\lt1}$ (correct?). Thus,
$$
f_Y(y)=\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt1}\int_\mathbb Rx^{-1}\mathbf 1_{y\lt x\lt 1}\mathrm dx=\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt1}\int_y^1x^{-1}\mathrm dx=(-\log y)\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt1}.
$$
See? This cannot fail...

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, i have the same density of X now after some corrections being pointed out.. is the rest of my answer correct? Should the density of Y be -ln x?

Comment: The density of Y is in my answer.